# C While loop not functioning properly

Tags: c

My program is supposed to read in numbers continuously and print the largest once the user inputs a negative number but the loop only seems to run once no matter what number is input.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int largest;
    int num;

    while (num >= 0) {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d%*c", num);
        if (num > largest) {
                num = largest;
        }
    }
    printf("%d is the largest.", &largest);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you have not initialized num to anything before using in loop.

Comment: You are reading the value of num inside the while loop. Try using do while

Comment: You probably want to reverse the assignment in the condition in the loop: `largest = num;` instead of `num = largest;`.  However, your loop could be terminating because the code is using `largest` uninitialized and the junk value in it is negative.  The code has undefined behaviour.  Revise it so that `largest` is initialized (`0` is probably appropriate) before the loop.

Comment: You should probably enable compiler warnings.

Comment: Why did you change your code in the question?

Comment: I updated it to fix the syntax errors but it still doesn't function properly.

Comment: There were no syntax errors.

Comment: Don't do that. That invalidates the answers. Your code should be as it was when you experienced problems.

Comment: Okay, should I change it back?

Comment: Only change the code if it does not represent your problematic code. If you use copy paste, this is completely unnecessary.

Comment: I have already changed it. Don't worry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several severe issues with your code.

First, `largest` is not initialized. It may have any value. Same for `num`.

Secondly, you should use the address operator for the `scanf` call like this `scanf("%d*c", &num)`. This is something you should have received a warning for if you turned on your compiler warnings.

Thirdly, you are not checking the return value for `scanf`. Do something like this:

```
if(scanf("%d*c", &num) != 1) { /* Code to handle error */ }
```

Fourthly, you should NOT use the address operator in the printf statement. Again, this is something you should have received a warning for.

Fifthly, `num=largest` should be `largest=num`.

Always compile your code with at least `gcc -Wall` but preferably `gcc -Wall -Wextra`. I use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -pedantic`. Then it can look like this:

```
$ gcc main.c -Wall
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:9:17: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
         scanf("%d%*c", num);
                ~^      ~~~
main.c:14:14: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("%d is the largest.", &largest);
             ~^                   ~~~~~~~~
             %ls
```

I would also suggest changing while to do-while. That's usually best when you want to run a loop *at least* once. It also removes the need to initialize `num`. Here is working code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int largest = -1;
    int num;

    do {
        printf("Enter a number: ");

        if (scanf("%d%*c", &num) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error reading number");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (num > largest) {
                largest = num;
        }
    } while (num >= 0); 

    printf("%d is the largest.\n", largest);
}
```

Also, something that can be worth mentioning is that in this code (and in your original code) it MAY happen that "Enter a number: " is not printed before you press enter at the `scanf` statement, or even not then. It's not likely, but it may happen. One way to avoid this is to do like this:

```
printf("Enter a number: ");
fflush(stdout); // Ensure that "Enter a number:" is printed before continuing
```

The reason is that `stdout` is a buffered stream. You can read about stream buffering here: https://eklitzke.org/stdout-buffering

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by compiler warnings though, I'm currently just using the terminal to compile with MinGW.

Comment: See my updated answer with examples of compiler warnings.

Comment: Also consider adding `fflush(stdout);` between `printf` / `scanf`.